# Boost Graph Library undirected_graph: how to specify the vertex type (e.g. as int)?

Tags: c++, boost, undirected-graph

is it possible to fix the type of the vertices in a `boost::undirected_graph` such to be, e.g., 'int'?

The 'int' vertex type seems to be the default with the `boost::adjacency_list`, and the following code works:

`boost::adjacency_list<  boost::vecS,  boost::vecS,  boost::undirectedS>  g;
 boost::add_edge(0  , 1  , g);`

but fails with an undirected_graph. What additional steps should I do to use the same syntax for adding vertices to an undirected_graph?

I need to use a `bron_kerbosch_all_cliques` algorithm which only accepts undirected_graph as input.

thanks

Comment: The adjacency list instance you showed is an undirected graph. What else do you want?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the remark, I slightly modified the post. I would use an adjacency_list, but the bron_kerbosch_all_cliques algorithm only works with undirected_graph's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to use a bron_kerbosch_all_cliques algorithm which only accepts undirected_graph as input.

The source tells me it accepts generic graphs (as BGL does):

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/graph/bron_kerbosch_all_cliques.hpp

The docs are hard to find (might be a bug in the quickbook definitions?), but here goes:

> *Requirements:* The `Graph` type must be a model of the **`AdjacencyMatrix`**,
>   **`IncidenceGraph`** concept and the `VertexIndexGraph`
>   concepts. [¹ Any `Graph` type that implements the `edge()`
>   function will satisfy the expression requirements for the
>   **`AdjacencyMatrix`**, but may incur additional overhead due non-constant
>   time complexity.].

Head over to **Concepts** page in BGL documentation to see which graph types fit the bill.

I see that the likely "missing link" is the VertexIndexGraph concept. You can likely achieve this by adding a `vertex_index_t` **[Interior Property](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html#sec:interior-properties)**

Comment: Thanks! The default boost version in the cluster I work is 1.41.0 (2009). And I could not get my code to compile. When using the most recent headers it works.